# How to convert Objective-C code to Swift code - errorhandling ,iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling

I'm trying to convert this text to swift:

```
- (void)sendData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSError *error;
    GameKitHelper *gameKitHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];

    BOOL success = [gameKitHelper.match
                    sendDataToAllPlayers:data
                    withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable
                    error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending data:%@", error.localizedDescription);
        [self matchEnded];
    }
}
```

Now I've gotten so far here:

```
func sendData(data: NSData) {
    var error: NSError?
    var gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedGameKitHelper()
    var success = try! gameKitHelper.match.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataReliable)
    if !success {
        print("Error sending data:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.matchEnded()
    }
}
```

But It's giving me an error at `if (!succes)` and I read on apples documentation that the objective-c version of `.sendDataToAllPlayers()` will return a bool but the swift version won't.

[Apple Documentation - GKMatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMatch/sendDataToAllPlayers:withDataMode:error:)

So how can I handle the error

Comment: If you lookup the documentation then you'll see that the Swift method does not return a boolean, it `throws` an error instead. Lookup "error handling" in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sendDataToAllPlayers` function throws an exception if an error occurs. You need a catch block to handle it:

```
func sendData(data: NSData) {
    var gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedGameKitHelper()
    do {
        try gameKitHelper.match.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: .Reliable)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error sending data:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.matchEnded()
    }

}
```